# How to modrewrite in my htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why my .htacces is not working? I have got pages:

> site.com/page.php

I want to see pages, like this:

> site.com/page/

htacces here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /(.*).php /$1
```

Also I want to see redirect from page.php to /page/ too

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```